# Can we use xamarin to test hybrid mobile app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I need to UI automate  a third party mobile app(hybrid app) using xamarin , in which first page is loaded from a website. When i give tree command in xamarin repl command prompt, it returns system web view element like below ,

```
[SystemWebView] id : "NoResourceEntry-100"
[dom]
[dom]
[dom]
```

It has two buttons SKIP and NEXT. 
Is it  possible to  retrieve the id to use SKIP or NEXT using xamarin repl. Kindly help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but you have to use the DOM or CSS IDs. Something like: `app.Tap(e => e.WebView(1).Css("your_css_selector"));`

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But there is no DOM or CSS Id's available .

Comment: You could use XPath to query the DOM too. But it might be easier to add a CSS identifier.